# sql server after insert trigger update 3 fields of inserted row, ONLY for specific users and ONLY if fields are blank

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I don't have access to the Insert Statement so if they are blank, I don't know if the blank fields are even part of the Insert statement to begin with. Office users and Field (tablet) users insert Work Order records using different applications. To keep the field users from having to populate their Crew Name, Supervisor's name and Shop Name on every record, I've put them into a lookup table keyed on the INITIATEDBY field from the Work Order record (which is auto populated by the app). Office workers may be creating Work orders for anyone but Field Crews only create work orders for their crews so when a Field crew inserts a record I want to populate the 3 fields for them. (Actually they cannot populate the 3 fields because I have hidden them on the Work Order form they use.)

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: I have no Idea where to start. I've never written a trigger before. I know a little sql but never done anything this complex before. I know I need to get the INITIATEDBY field from the inserted data to do a lookup and if no record is found I do nothing. Otherwise I need to insert the data from the lookup query into the 3 fields. If the update was always done, I might be able to get a join to work but the conditional is throwing me off.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you are making this a LOT harder than it needs to be. Why not populate those values from the front end. There is nothing that says values have to come from visible user controls. Just populate them on page load and make them hidden or whatever. Honestly triggers are something that be used VERY rarely (auditing is a great example). Using triggers to manage business rules like this is a recipe for a painful system in the long run.

Comment: I edited the trigger code I posted here to hide real names and I missed one. The Update statement should by update dbo.ESDWO instead of dbo.WorkOrder

Comment: Thanks Sean, that looks more like what I was hoping to be able to do but I never saw enough examples to do it myself. FYI: The field crews are using an Android native app (not browser based) so your suggestion about filling these fields at page load wasn't possible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger code needs to be a set based approach. In the answer you posted you assume there will only be a single row in inserted. Something like this more along the lines of what you want.

This would be the ENTIRE body of the trigger.

```
Update w
set Crew = tu.Crew
    , SHOP = tu.Shop
    , Supervisor = tu.Supervisor
from inserted i
join TableUsers tu on tu.EmpName = i.INITBY
join WorkOrder w on i.ID = w.WOID
```

Answer (score -2):

I figures it out myself. I just had to read enough examples to put it all together. The only thing that scares me is the IF @EMPName <> ''. Is there a better way to check if a record was retrieved in the 2nd select statement?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateCrewShopSuper ON ESDWO
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID nvarchar(60), @InitBy nvarchar(50), @EMPName nvarchar(50), @CREW as nvarchar(50), @Shop nvarchar(100), @Super nvarchar(50);

select @ID=i.ID, @InitBy=i.INITBY from inserted i;

select @EMPName=EmpName, @CREW=CrewName, @Shop=SHOP, @Super=Supervisor 
    From dbo.TabletUsers 
    WHERE EmpName = @InitBy
IF @EMPName <> ''  
    BEGIN
        update dbo.WorkOrder 
        set Crew = @Crew, SHOP = @Shop, Supervisor = @Super
        WHERE WOID = @ID
    END
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes that will only ever be one row in inserted. This is not the case as triggers fire once per operation. You need to rewrite your update statement so it is set based.

Comment: To check if a select statement returned any rows you should use @@ROWCOUNT.